# SSMS division in query not giving correct calculation

Tags: sql, database, ssms

So I'm trying to create a temporary column to give me the result of dividing two columns in SSMS. Here's the code:

```
select * from testdb.dbo.us_state_6digitnaics_2019
where NAICS in ('311611', '311615')

select PAYR/EMPL*1000 as PAYR_per_EMPLOYEE from TESTDB.dbo.us_state_6digitnaics_2019
```

[Output of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQg26.png)

Why would this be? Am I formatting something incorrectly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Integer division most likely. Use something like `1000.00`

Comment: Side note, SSMS is not doing any division.

Comment: @Stu to be honest I'm not sure what you mean... would you mind explaining?

Comment: @shawnt00 just tried that... still getting the same output except now the PAYR_per_EMPLOYEE column has .00 on the end of each row.

Comment: Actually since the division comes before you multiply you should reorder so the `1000.00` is out front. I misread where the division was coming in.

Comment: @CJeskeTech - it's just terminology, SSMS is a GUI, it sends the query statement to SQL Server, SQL Server parses, compiles and executes the query, SSMS just displays the result.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#result-types

Comment: @shawnt00 just tried doing that... the calculations changed but they're still not mathematically correct.

Comment: Ultimately, when two integers are divided the remainder is truncated from the result. One of the operands needs to be a `decimal` type before the division is performed.

Comment: @shawnt00 ... I see. How could I fix that?

Comment: `PAYR * 1000.00 / EMPL` would convert the numerator before the division since it will operate left to right. An explicit cast is another way. Since the results don't match up in your grid, I'm not 100% certain there isn't something else at play though.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yeah that works to get the actual full integer and decimals. My only issue is that the math just isn't right... I'm still getting an output that's like 9,000 off what it should be... is there a problem in my database?

Comment: I think you should give a specific example.

Comment: @shawnt00 so for the first row in the picture I linked in the original question, the value in PAYR is 7492045 and the value for EMPL is 166495. If we divide this and then multiply by 1000 we should get a value of 44,998.6186. But, SQL is returning a value of 55858.227.

Comment: Hi @CleskeTech, I don't think there is anything wrong with your server. It is just that you seem to be running two queries separately, and expecting the rows to be returned in the same order. that is not the case. Referring to your screenshot, the row #1 in the first query is returned as row #2 in the second query. Put the calculation as a new column in the first query and then run. Alternatively order both by the same unique column, if any.

Comment: Reinforcing what @tinazmu has said, include FIRM in your request so you can see which result is which.

Comment: @tinazmu Oh my goodness that worked! I don't know why I thought running it as two queries was a good idea. Thank you to you and everyone else that has helped.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the nominator to decimal:

```
select PAYR * 1.0 / EMPL * 1000 as PAYR_per_EMPLOYEE from TESTDB.dbo.us_state_6digitnaics_2019;
```

Comment: This gives me the entire integers including decimals, but the actual calculations are off somewhere in the range of 9,000... why is that?